Ignoring word when its between a specific combination of words in regex (glossary link implantation)
I have edited my question and simplified it.
I created a function to highlight glossary in text that can be used to highlight conjugated words (in french).  I works great but I want to ignore words that have been already highlighted.  So I need a way to ignore any words between let say  (I simplified it)
Can someone edit my regex so it ignores words between theses tags?
Here is my function's important part :
// example glossary but the real one has 10,000 entries
$words = ["example","ample"];
$content = "Here is an example for you."

foreach($words as $word) {
  ///// ***** HERE IS THE PROBLEMATIC REGEX.  The esxu is for french conjugaison *****
  $search = "/([\s\x{00A0} ,\.-;-\(\)\"\'>])(" . $word  . ")([esxu]{0,3})([\s\x{00A0} ,\.;\"--\)\(<])/iu";

  $content = preg_replace_callback($search, function ($words) {
      return $words[1] . '<tag>' . $words[2] .  $words[3] . '</tag>' . $words[4];
    } , $content );
   }
}

Currently I would get
Here is an <tag>ex<tag>ample</tag></tag> for you.

But I want
Here is an <tag>example</tag> for you.

So I need some regex pattern that says if there is :
<tag>XXX</tag>

ignore XXX in the search subsequent searches (here the "ample" search).
/////// EDIT //////
/////// EDIT //////
OK @mickmackusa answer might work for me. But my final goal is to be able to add my onClick function with the word (not conjugated) in parameters.  For just now I don't know How I could get only the central part (the original word) in my onclick.  Here is an example and check the conjugated "examples" word.
$words = ["example", "ample"];
$content = "Here is an example examples my-example for you.";

// As cited in comment - and - are not the same charcode (long and small hyphens and are used both in my DB.  I removed un-necessary \
$regex = "#[\s\x{00A0} ,.;()\"'>--]\K(?:" . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $words))  . ")[esxu]{0,3}(?=[\s\x{00A0} ,.;\"--)(<])#iu";

echo preg_replace($regex, '<tag onClick="showGlossaire(\'$0\')">$0</tag>', $content);

// Output : Here is an <tag onClick="showGlossaire('example')">example</tag> <tag onClick="showGlossaire('examples')">examples</tag> my-<tag onClick="showGlossaire('example')">example</tag> for you.


Ins\i\de y\our \cha\rac\ter c\l\a\ss, \you a\re us\i\ng u\n\ecess\a\ry \es\ap\i\n\g.

To ensure that your regex only makes one pass, implode all of your words into a piped subpattern.  Be sure to order your longer "words" before shorter "words" so that shorter matches aren't matched before larger ones.
You don't need preg_replace_callback() because you aren't making any function calls in the replacement parameter.
My naked eye can't tell if those repeated hyphens are unique, nor do I know if your intention is to match literal hyphens or make character ranges.  If you intend to match hyphens in your character class, move them to the end to remove amibiguity.
You don't need any capturing groups for this task.
Code: (Demo)
$words = ["example", "ample"];
$content = "Here is an example for you.";

$regex = "#[\s\x{00A0} ,.;()\"'>-]\K(?:" . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $words))  . ")[esxu]{0,3}(?=[\s\x{00A0} ,.;\"-)(<])#iu";

echo preg_replace($regex, '<tag>$0</tag>', $content);
// Here is an <tag>example</tag> for you.


Update after feedback from asker: use a capture group to isolate the "un-conjugated" word from the fullstring match.  I'll extend the pattern to allow matching a word at the start or end of the string.  Also, if your javascript function is expecting a completely lowercase string, then you can use preg_replace_callback() to call mb_strtolower(). (Demo)
$startingBoundaryChars = '[\s\x{00A0} ,.;()"\-\->\']';
$trailingBoundaryChars = '[\s\x{00A0} ,.;()"\-\-<]';
$pipedWhitelist = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $words));
$optionalSuffix = '[esxu]{0,3}';

$regex = "#(?:^|$startingBoundaryChars)\K($pipedWhitelist)$optionalSuffix(?=$trailingBoundaryChars)#iu";

echo preg_replace_callback(
         $regex,
         fn($m) => '<tag onclick="showGlossaire(\'' . mb_strtolower($m[1]) . '\')">' . $m[0] . '</tag>',
         $content
     );
// <tag onclick="showGlossaire('ample')">Ampleux</tag> is an <tag onclick="showGlossaire('example')">example</tag> <tag onclick="showGlossaire('example')">examples</tag> my-<tag onclick="showGlossaire('example')">example</tag> for you.


Thanks, yes those characters are intended characters that represent all characters that can be a start of a word in my html input ( ,.-;-()"'>) so that example ,example my-example (example "example l'example .. etc is matched in my function. I am currently testing your answer.  And I need the two -- since they are not the same char code (long and short hyphen) and are used in the site.. I edited my question to see if you can help with my problem with the onClick.

Updated my answer for you

Thanks it really nice I will be testing implementation soon.
